# I'm having trouble with a height and color animation (CSS only) staying at the last keyframe

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a battery animation that is working fine and all, but I can't seem to get the animation to stay at the last keyframe. The animation is a battery filling and at the last keyframe I have the height at 40% when it's full and the battery sort of glows, but the animation won't stay at the keyframe 100%. I have tried using the `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` but is doesn't work.

```css
@keyframes battery-charge {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
    background: #ff0000;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #ff0000);
  }
  20% {
    height: 50%;
    background: orange;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px orange);
  }
  40% {
    height: 100%;
    background: #00ff00;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #00ff00);
  }
  60% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 100px #00ff00);
  }
  70% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0px #00ff00);
  }
  90% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 100px #00ff00);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {
    background-color: #00ff00;
  }
  100% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 100px #00ff00);
    opacity: .5;
    background: #00ff00;
  }
}

.battery-body {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 18px;
}

.charge {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 14px;
  animation: battery-charge 7s linear 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="battery-body">
  <div class="charge"></div>
</div>
```

I was trying to use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`. I was expecting it to work perfectly fine but it didn't. The inside of the battery just went to the background color after the last keyframe. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Just set the height to `100%` initially and let the animation run. Now the *battery* will remain *charged* once the animation finishes.

Comment: set `height:100%` to `.charge` div

Answer (score 0):

```
.charge {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
@keyframes battery-charge {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
    background: #ff0000;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #ff0000);
  }
  20% {
    height: 50%;
    background: orange;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px orange);
  }
  40% {
    height: 100%;
    background: #00ff00;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #00ff00);
  }
  60% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 100px #00ff00);
  }
  70% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0px #00ff00);
  }
  90% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 100px #00ff00);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {
    background-color: #00ff00;
  }
  100% {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 100px #00ff00);
    opacity: .5;
    background: #00ff00;
  }
}

.battery-body {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 18px;
}

.charge {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 14px;
  animation: battery-charge 7s linear 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="battery-body">
  <div class="charge"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you also need to have a background property and filter property on your charge class to begin with otherwise it still fades out

```css
@keyframes battery-charge {
  0% {
    height: 0%;
    background: #ff0000;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #ff0000);
  }
  20% {
    height: 50%;
    background: orange;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px orange);
  }
  40% {
    height: 100%;
    background: #00ff00;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #00ff00);
  }
}

.battery-body {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 18px;
}

.charge {
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#00ff00;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px #00ff00);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 14px;
  animation: battery-charge 7s linear 1;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="battery-body">
  <div class="charge"></div>
</div>
```